# Surface element - spherical shell

Tags: integration, geometry, calculus

Say there is a spherical shell with radius $R$ and width $h$. For a certain purpose, I wanted to divide this object into many "rings with holes". Signifying by $\theta$ the polar angle, we have annulus with radii of $R\sin\theta$ throughout the shell ($\theta$ ranging from $\pi$ to $0$). On the one hand, shouldn't the surface of each annulus be simply $\pi(R^2-(R-h)^{2})$? But on the other hand, a surface element is $hR\sin\theta\ d\varphi$, and we get:
$\int_0^{2\pi} hR\sin\theta\ d\varphi = 2\pi R\sin\theta h$ ?
I see the latter is essentially the result, but why is the first calculation wrong? Is there a better way to deal with it? It is pretty simple, I have no idea why I struggle dealing with this.

[image]

*The width h is radially outwards

Comment: Width h?  Is h = 2R?

Comment: No, the shell has an outer surface a distance $R$ and an inner one a distance $R-h$, it has a small volume in between.

Comment: If $0 <\theta <\pi$ then surely $\theta$ is the polar angle? You appear to be using $\varphi$ as the azimuthal angle. And I don't understand why you think the surface (area?) of each annulus is $\pi(R^2 - (R-h)^2)$. That would be the surface area of an annulus, not the outer surface of a slice through your shell.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where does $h$ come into this at all? What do you mean by "width $h$"? How many slices are you dividing the shell into?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I added a picture. I want to sum these ring with a hole inside.

Comment: But if the rings are "thin" they don't have any outer surface area.

Answer (score 1):

This quotation was edit after my answer!!!
[image]

Surface Element is:

$$S=\int_0^\theta\int_0^{2\pi}r\,d\theta\,r\,\sin(\theta)\,d\phi=2\pi\,r^2\,(1-\cos(\theta))$$

your surface is:

$$S_y=2\pi\,r\,\sin(\theta)\,h$$

thus:

$$h=r\,\frac{1-\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$$

your Ansatz for the surface equation is:

$$S_c(h)=\pi\,(r^2-(r-h)^2)=\pi \, \left( {r}^{2}- \left( r+{\frac {r \left( -1+\cos \left( \theta
 \right)  \right) }{\sin \left( \theta \right) }} \right) ^{2}
 \right) 
$$

thus  $S_c\ne S$;  your Ansatz is wrong

**Edit**

[image]

the half   surface area is

$$S=\int_{R-h}^R\int_0^\pi\,r\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta=R^2-(R-h)^2$$

Comment: Thank you, but you got the wrong picture (bad wording from my part, sorry). See the edited post please.

Comment: @Darkenin I add  new calculation